# Springboot issues with Content-Type xml & json Request & Response payloads

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to understand how can i fix this particular problem with configuration/dependencies changes.

Java Version: 1.8

Springboot version: 2.7.17

Request & Response Model Schemas are generated from the XSD schema.

I have tried to debug with a small project to debug & looking for some solution

What's happening:

when I tried XML payloads  the Request & Response models were as expected because of `@XmlElement` Name attributes, however when tried with JSON payloads it respect class fields rather than `@XmlElement` Name Attribute.

Looking for some solution to fix this particular problem where I will not be allowed to change the definition of XSD, but open to changing the Parsing logic with some kind of configuration change.

**Limitations:** our XSD files have been maintained for years & POJO classes will be generated using the `cxf-codegen-plugin` version `3.0.3` and goal `wsdl2java` . Hence I will not get the green light to change the POJO Schemas. Asked politely to provide a backward-compatible solution.

Here's the equivalent sample project for easier debugging:

**XML payload:**

```
POST http://localhost:9990/api/v1/users/test
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/json

<InputRequest>
    <ACCOUNT_NO>12</ACCOUNT_NO>
    <FLAGS>2</FLAGS>
    <POID>1.0.0</POID>
    <PRODUCTS elem="0">
        <CODE>1400337</CODE>
    </PRODUCTS>
</InputRequest>
```

**JSON payload:**

```
POST http://localhost:9990/api/v1/users/test
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json

{
  "ACCOUNT_NO": "122",
  "FLAGS": 2,
  "POID": "1.0.0",
  "PRODUCTS": {
    "CODE": "1222",
    "ELEM": 0
  }
}
```

**Expected Response:**

```
{
  "ACCOUNT_NO": "122",
  "FLAGS": 2,
  "POID": "1.0.0",
  "PRODUCTS": {
    "CODE": "1222",
    "ELEM": 0
  }
}
```

**Realiity:**

```
{
  "accountno": null,
  "flags": 0,
  "poid": null,
  "products": []
}
```

**POJO** (Generated from XSD)**:**

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
        name = "",
        propOrder = {"accountno", "flags", "poid", "products"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
        name = "InputRequest"
)
public class InputRequest implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(
            name = "ACCOUNT_NO",
            required = true
    )
    protected String accountno;

    @XmlElement(
            name = "FLAGS"
    )
    protected int flags;
    @XmlElement(
            name = "POID",
            required = true
    )
    protected String poid;
    @XmlElement(
            name = "PRODUCTS",
            required = true
    )
    protected List<PRODUCTS> products;

    public InputRequest() {
    }

    public String getACCOUNTNO() {
        return this.accountno;
    }

    public void setACCOUNTNO(String value) {
        this.accountno = value;
    }


    public int getFLAGS() {
        return this.flags;
    }

    public void setFLAGS(int value) {
        this.flags = value;
    }

    public String getPOID() {
        return this.poid;
    }

    public void setPOID(String value) {
        this.poid = value;
    }

    public List<PRODUCTS> getPRODUCTS() {
        if (this.products == null) {
            this.products = new ArrayList();
        }

        return this.products;
    }

    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(
            name = ""
    )
    public static class PRODUCTS extends CODE implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @XmlAttribute(
                name = "elem"
        )
        protected String elem;

        public PRODUCTS() {
        }

        public String getElem() {
            return this.elem;
        }

        public void setElem(String value) {
            this.elem = value;
        }
    }
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(
            propOrder = {"code"}
    )
     public static class CODE implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @XmlElement(
                name = "CODE",
                required = true
        )
        protected String code;

        public CODE() {
        }

        public String getCODE() {
            return this.code;
        }

        public void setCODE(String value) {
            this.code = value;
        }
    }

}
```

**Rest Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/users")
public class TestController {

    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PostMapping(consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE},value = "/test")
    public InputRequest echoXmlUser(@RequestBody InputRequest payload) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(payload));
        return payload;
    }

}
```

**pom.xml** (trying with different depdencies)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>2.7.17</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
       <java.version>8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
       </dependency>

       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
<!--       <dependency>-->
<!--          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>-->
<!--          <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>-->
<!--          <version>2.4.0</version>-->
<!--       </dependency>-->
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
          <version>2.3.8</version>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                <image>
                   <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                </image>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to explore few options with `jackson-dataformat-xml` & `jaxb-runtime` libraries & trying to adjust configuration to make it work.

I am looking for some options where this POJO remains constant(due to limitations of wider imact by different clients if  changed) & also support both XML & JSON payload with the configuration change/depedency change. I also do not want to do much changes inside the controller because i have 50 such different controllers are also needed to get changed if such thing were to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use the [JAXB Module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-base/tree/master/jaxb) to allow Jackson to use JAXB annotations for metadata. With that added as a dependency you need to add an `@Bean` method to expose the `JaxbAnnotationModule` so it will be picked up by Spring Boot and added to Jackson.

```java
@Bean
public JaxbAnnotationModule jaxbAnnotationModule() {
  return new JaxbAnnotationModule();
}
```

The dependency

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>tools.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I suspect that Spring Boot will manage the version of the `jackson-module-jaxb-annotations` for you (through the included `jackson-bom`). If not you should be able to use `${jackson.version}` as the `<version>` as that will contain the Jackson version in use for your Spring Boot version.

Comment: you deserve a ton, I have been trying to dig & dig into it for the last 1 week, and it's working thanks for your reply. it was difficult to debug & no there's hardly resources available to point what's going wrong